# Get file information using absolute file url only

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Say my filepath is `http://server/subsite/library/folder/file.png`. If I need to get information about a file, I need to do the following:

`http://server/subsite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/subsite/library/folder/file.png')`.

Now the problem is I don't know which sections are the subsite(s), so I have to run the follow `_vti_bin/webs.asmx/WebUrlFromPageUrl` which will get me the web url. So for the above filepath it will return `http://server/subsite` and now I have the required context for the REST _api.

Is there an easier way of doing this? I'm relying on the REST api and the I know the asmx handlers are very old and deprecated. I don't mind doing two requests to get the information I want but is there a REST equivalent of `_vti_bin/webs.asmx/WebUrlFromPageUrl`?

Edit: I am calling the sharepoint rest api from an external service. It is not a sharepoint app.

Comment: For me (NGINX), given an any URL, it's not easy to get its `webServerRelativeUrl/webAbsoluteUrl/siteAbsoluteUrl/siteServerRelativeUrl` from `_spPageContextInfo` in JavaScript of a client browser or something, I also made a HTTP request (WebUrlFromPageUrl). If worrying about asmx handlers are very old and deprecated, maybe use new OData API (i.e. https://{{SPWebServer}}/_api/sp.web.getweburlfrompageurl(@v)?@v='xx') with `X-RequestDigest` header. See also https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224893/pnp-sp-site-getweburlfrompageurl-method-is-returning-wrong-web-url

Comment: The preceding `{{SPWebServer}}` may look like `{{tenant}}.sharepoint.com` or `sharepoint.company0.com` and it doesn't need `siteServerRelativeUrl`. And the API returns `webAbsoluteUrl/siteAbsoluteUrl`, e.g. `{"value":"https://company0test2.sharepoint.com/tit"}` for `@v='https://company0test2.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/tit/EeFmOJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-eb0xxxxxxxxxxl1g?e=9kXxdl'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you may test is the one described [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/navigate-the-sharepoint-data-structure-represented-in-the-rest-service):

> 1. Start with a URL to a given SharePoint item. For example: http://site/web/doclib/myDocument.docx
> 2. Remove the name of the specific resource from the end of the URL, so that the URL points to a document library, folder, or list. IN this
>      case: http://site/web/doclib/
> 3. Append the REST service pointer and the /contextinfo operator to the URL: http://site/web/doclib/_api/contextinfo
> 4. Read the form digest and webFullUrl properties from the response.
> 5. Append the REST service pointer _api to the web URL
> 6. Use the resulting URL and the form digest to make requests for other resources you need.