# pnp.sp.site.getWebUrlFromPageUrl method is returning wrong web URL

Tags: spfx, pnp-js-core, npm

I am using sp-pnp-js for my spfx project. **GetWebUrlFromPageUrl** method is returning wrong URL that includes sitePages also. Please refer:
my current page location is
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/SitePages/Search.aspx

The above method is returning web url as:
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/SitePages

rather it should return:
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/

```
pnp.sp.site.getWebUrlFromPageUrl(window.location.href)
 .then(res => {
 alert(res);
});
```

> Please note this issue is not appearing in workbench. This appears
>   only when  only when I deployed the code to SharePoint site

What am I missing?

**Edit 1:** Screen shot- see the current URL is having /SitePages/. But if I run the same from workbench it doesn't throw error

[image]

Comment: are you trying to get the current web in your code ?

Comment: Yes, Gautam. Please see my question edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why `GetWebUrlFromPageUrl` is not working. But as you mentioned in the comment that you want the current sp web url, you can use the `this.context.pageContext` object.

No need to make a REST api call to get the current sp web url.

For example, in the render method, using React, it is available as below:

```
public render(): void {
const element: React.ReactElement<any > = React.createElement(
   HelloWorld,
   {
     spWebUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl     
   }
);

 ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

Or, using it in a simple no-framework solution as below:

```
let spWebUrl = '';
public render(): void {
    spWebUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
}
```

After that, you can use the `spWebUrl` anywhere in your code.

I believe that this will be a much faster and correct way to get the current web url. `GetWebUrlFromPageUrl` internally made a POST request to the `_api/sp.web.getweburlfrompageurl(@v)` endpoint and then gave you the data(in your case, incorrect data). However, `this.context.pageContext` object saves you this API call and provides the correct result.

Comment: hey @dvg, did you try this approach ?

Comment: This will not work for me as I am using Knockout.js and this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl works on webpart.ts file only. However my core logic is written under webpartViewModel.ts file... Thanks nyway

Comment: ok kind-of understood, you can use `import { PageContext } from '@microsoft/sp-page-context';` in your `webpartViewModel.ts` file and then use the context variable , or else pass the value from `webpart.ts` to `webpartViewModel.ts` file somehow, not sure how though :)

Answer (score 0):

if it helps someone else I had the same problem and to solve it had to initiate the `pnp.setup`

```
 public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => { 
      pnp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
      });
      });
  }
```